# Does anyone know how to implement SecureStorage in React Native?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am using JavaScript + React Native to make an app for my university project. I am using expo to manage my packaging and for viewing the app in the iOS simulator. I am also new to both JavaScript and React Native.

I have been having trouble with implementing a React Native module known as *Secure Storage*.

https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/securestore/

I would like to store user data for the app. Specifically I would like to store a JavaScript object such as:

```
User{ name:"Bob", age:"20" }
```

And recall it later.

Having read the documentation, I have made a helper module called "StorageHelper" as seen below:

```html
import * as SecureStore from 'expo-secure-store';

/**
 * Stores data
 * @param {} key 
 * @param {*} value 
 */
export async function storeObject(key, value)
{
  try 
  {
    const jsonValue = JSON.stringify(value);
    await SecureStore.setItemAsync(key, jsonValue);
  } 
  catch(e) 
  {
    console.log(e.message);
  }
}

/**
 * Retrieves data
 * @param {} key 
 */
export async function getObject(key) 
{
  let result = await SecureStore.getItemAsync(key);
  if (result != null) 
  {
    return result;
  } 
  else 
  {
    alert('No values stored under that key.');
  }
```

On this screen in the app flow, I would like to generate the userObject object and store it in the *SecureStorage*. This following is

```html
import React from 'react';
import { Text, View, TouchableOpacity, Image } from 'react-native';

import ProjStyleSheet from "../styles/ProjStyleSheet.js";

import * as StorageHelper from "../resources/StorageHelper.js";

const HomeImage = require('../art/HomeImage.png');
const styles = ProjStyleSheet;

function HomeScreen({ navigation }) {

  var userData = "Bob"; // instead of the object, I'm just using a simple variable.
  StorageHelper.storeObject("userName",userData);
  
  return (
    <View style={{
      backgroundColor: "#fff",
      flexDirection: "column",
      justifyContent: "flex-start",
      flex:1,}}>
        <View style = {{
          paddingTop: 100, 
          paddingBottom: 20,
          paddingLeft: 10,
          paddingRight: 10,
          }}> 
          <Text style={styles.titleText}>University Money Management App</Text>
        </View>
        <View style = {{
          justifyContent: "space-evenly", 
          alignItems: "center",
          }}> 
          <Image
            style={{width: 250, height: 250, paddingBottom:20}}
            source={HomeImage}/>
          <TouchableOpacity style={styles.defaultButton} 
          onPress={() => navigation.navigate('IntroName')}> 
            <Text style={styles.text}> Get Started </Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
    </View>
  );
}

export default HomeScreen;
```

In the next screen, I am trying to get the data from the secure storage and show it on the screen. This can be seen below:

```html
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Text, View, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
import ProjStyleSheet from "../styles/ProjStyleSheet.js";
import { TextInput } from 'react-native-gesture-handler';

import * as StorageHelper from "../resources/StorageHelper.js";

const styles = ProjStyleSheet;

function IntroName({ navigation }) 
{
    var name = StorageHelper.getObject("userName"); // retrieve the variable here.
    
    return (
        <View style={{
            flex: 1,
            backgroundColor: "#fff",
            alignItems: 'center',
            justifyContent: "space-around",}}>
            <Text style={styles.titleText}>Please Enter Your Name</Text>
            <Text> test = {name} </Text> // show the name here
            <TextInput 
                style={{
                    borderColor: "#000",
                    borderRadius: 10,
                    borderWidth: 2,
                    padding: 20,
                    fontSize: 20,
                    width: "75%",
                }}
                placeholder="Your name here.">
            </TextInput>
            <TouchableOpacity  
                style={styles.defaultButton}  
                onPress={() => navigation.navigate("IntroIncome")}>
                    <Text style={styles.text}>Next</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
    );
}

export default IntroName;
```

Unfortunately, no name appears in the text where I intend it to. I have gone through the Secure Storage documentation and searched through the internet, however I cannot find any answers that can help me. Does anyone have any good ideas on what I am missing to fully implement *SecureStorage*?

Comment: First thing I would confirm is: is it actually getting stored. When you store it, can you immediately retrieve it `const res = await SecureStore.getItemAsync("userName");` and log the value.

Comment: Hi @Tony, when I console.log() the output of getItemAsync, I get the following output: 
`Promise {
  "_U": 0,
  "_V": 0,
  "_W": null,
  "_X": null,
}`

Interestingly enough, when I copy and paste the demo found on the documentation, it does seem to store the variables. However, it only stores the variable on that particular screen itself.

Comment: [Promise handling](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises). It's a promise, one way to get the resolve promises is `async/await`. `async () => await SecureStore.getItemAsync("userName");`

Comment: @Tony thank you for the response. Just to update on my progress, I still have not been able to resolve this issue. I have just updated the methods so that they handle promises, i.e using the await and async keywords. I also changed my screens so that they are aReact.Component as opposed to a function. However, after handling the promise, the `console.log(await SecureStore.getItemAsync("user"));` returns: `Can't find variable: SecureStore`

Comment: I do want to add that if I call the `await SecureStore.setItemAsync("user",this.name)` and `console.log(await SecureStore.getItemAsync("user"));` on the same screen, it DOES return the correct data. Something tells me that I might be doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the solution is quite simple. Thanks to the advice of @Tony, I converted all my function components to class components. Within those class components, I wrote an async method which calls the SecureStore method as such: `await SecureStore.setItemAsync("user",this.name)`.

The async method updates the state of the screen, i.e

```js
class Scren extends React.Component
{
  constructor()
  {
    super();
    this.state={
      data:0,
    };
  }
  
  async getObject()
  {
    let result = JSON.parse(await SecureStore.getItemAsync("data");

    this.setState({
      data: result,
    };
  }
}
```